# Does visualforce/soql not respect field precision?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, fields

I've got a webservice that generates some XML for a templating engine to make some sales collateral. Noticing that in some cases users get a ton of extra decimal places in the output for one calculation, even though the field has (16,2) precision. Is this known visualforce behavior?

When I query the field in the developer console I can see the extra precision as well, I'd just expected things to get rounded based on the field metadata before coming back from the server.

For example imaging my field gets updated by a trigger with 10/3 (or 3.33333333), I'd expect that to get stored and returned based on the defined precision for the field. If that precision is (16,2) I'd expect any output to be 3.33, but that doesn't seem to happen in practice.

The data is generated via a component and am hoping to avoid adding extra logic to handle rounding if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the precision applies to the Visualforce presentation only.

For some careful money based calculation in our Apex code, we explicitly call [setScale](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_setScale_2) on intermediate values that are later stored to ensure that values like 3.3333333333 don't introduce fraction of a cent errors. I suggest that adding such logic before you store is the way to go.

**PS**

With a many decimal place value stored in (in a field set to 2 decimal places) this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Payment__c">
Field=<apex:outputField value="{!Payment__c.Net__c}"/>
Text=<apex:outputText value="{!Payment__c.Net__c}"/>
Raw={!Payment__c.Net__c}
</apex:page>
```

displays:

> Field=$3.33 Text=3.333333333 Raw=3.333333333

demonstrating how a many decimal places value has its scale set when presented as a field (where the scale information is available).

Comment: I'm assuming that also means, only via <apex:inputField> tags? We're outputting this in visualforce, but since it's an xml document we're using naked merge fields since we don't want any extra markup.

Comment: @Ralph Yep looks that way - see addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This came up again recently, and dug up some historical research I did that I should have posted a while ago.

> All tests done with a percent field with varying levels of decimal
>   precision as of 6/17/12
>
> On display in visual force:
>
> - output text: no rounding occurs
> - output field: rounds to field precision HALF_EVEN
> - input field: rounds to max of field precision or 3 HALF_UP
> - input text: no rounding occurs
>
> On return to controller:
>
> - (decimal places = 0) input field: rounded to nearest integer DOWN
> - (decimal places > 0) input field: rounded to field precision HALF_UP
> - input text: no rounding occurs
>
> When displayed in standard salesforce page:
>
> - rounds to field precision HALF_EVEN
>
> When displayed in standard salesforce edit page:
>
> - rounds to max of field precision or 3 HALF_UP
>
> When entered on standard salesforce page:
>
> - (decimal places = 0) rounds to nearest integer DOWN
> - (decimal places > 0) rounds to field precision HALF_UP
>
> When committed to database (via apex):
>
> - stored up to max decimal precision with no rounding (throws runtime error if max decimal precision exceeded)
>
> When queried from the database
>
> - returns as much precision as available
>
> Formula fields
>
> - uses full precision available to source fields in database and rounds the result HALF_UP to formula field precision
> - no additional precision available in queries versus display